# Looping through the parsed JSON string?

Tags: apex, json

I have used [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) to create a wrapper class from my JSON string. So far, all good. 
My JSON string is somewhat like this:

```
String json = '{' +
    '\"MasterData\": {' +
    '\"RecordCount\": 21,' +
    '\"FormDataRecords\": {' +
        '\"FormData\": [' +
                '{' +
                    '\"FormID\": 930471394,' +
                    '\"FormDateTime\": \"2013-03-11T00:00:00.000+05:30\",' +
                    '\"Amount\": 330,' +
                    '\"Balance\": 0,' +
                    '\"Addons\": {' +
                        '\"Addon\": [' +
                                    '{' +
                                        '\"AddonType\": \"Quicker\",' +
                                        '\"AddonDesc\": \"This is a special Addon\"' +
                                    '}' +
                                ']' +
                        '}' +
                '},' +
                '{' +
                    '\"FormID\": 330471949,' +
                    '\"FormDateTime\": \"2013-03-11T00:00:00.000+05:30\",' +
                    '\"Amount\": 450,' +
                    '\"Balance\": 10,' +
                    '\"Addons\": {' +
                        '\"Addon\": [' +
                                    '{' +
                                        '\"AddonType\": \"Flash\",' +
                                        '\"AddonDesc\": \"This is a special Addon\"' +
                                    '}' +
                                ']' +
                        '}' +
                '}' +
            ']' +
        '}' +
    '}' +
    '}'
```

After successful parsing the above JSON string using my JSON2Apex class, I was able to loop through the the `FormData` list like this:

```
for(Integer i=0; i<obj.MasterData.FormDataRecords.FormData.size(); i++){
  System.debug('FormID of '+ i +' is: ' +obj.MasterData.FormDataRecords.FormData[i].FormID);
}
```

My question is, is the above way of looping through the list of records is a good practice? If not, can I use the standard loop: `for(Object obj: objList)` or any other good approach?

**Update:**

This is what I would get once I deserialize using my parser class:

```
[MasterData=MasterData:
[FormDataRecords=FormDataRecords:
   [FormData=
       (
         FormData:[Addons=Addons:[Addon=(Addon:[AddonDesc=This is a special Addon, AddonType=Quicker])], Amount=330, Balance=0, FormDateTime=2013-03-11T00:00:00.000+05:30, FormID=930471394], 
         FormData:[Addons=Addons:[Addon=(Addon:[AddonDesc=This is a special Addon, AddonType=Flash])], Amount=450, Balance=10, FormDateTime=2013-03-11T00:00:00.000+05:30, FormID=330471949]
      )
    ], 
RecordCount=21]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bit easier to read if you just iterate through directly, without index:

```
for (JSON2Apex.FormData data : obj.MasterData.FormDataRecords.FormData)
{
    String formId = data.FormId;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Adrian, I have tried this and I get the error: `Invalid Type: FormData`. I know why I am seeing this, but how can I overcome it?

Comment: You have not showed us any of the structure you are deserializing into...

Comment: Updated my question with it.

Comment: @AustinEvans Is `FormData` an inner class in some other class? You would need to use the fully qualified type name.

Comment: That's great. yeah, I got it working once I had the full path in place. Can you please edit your answer with `JSON2Apex.FormData`, so that I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

To add to @AdrianLarson's answer, you should iterate directly. 
I have just generated the JSON2Apex class myself based on the above JSON string and I was able to loop through the FormData records in this way:

```
for(JSON2Apex.FormData data: obj.MasterData.FormDataRecords.FormData){
     System.debug('FormId: ' +data.FormId);
}
```

JSON2Apex class:

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//
 public class JSON2Apex {

 public class FormData {
    public Integer FormID;
    public String FormDateTime;
    public Integer Amount;
    public Integer Balance;
    public Addons Addons;
 }

 public class Addon {
    public String AddonType;
    public String AddonDesc;
 }

 public class MasterData {
    public Integer RecordCount;
    public FormDataRecords FormDataRecords;
 }

 public MasterData MasterData;

 public class Addons {
    public List<Addon> Addon;
 }

 public class FormDataRecords {
    public List<FormData> FormData;
 }


 public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
    return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
 }
}
```